# What's seats? (Blender Market)

Tags: rigging

I'm looking to get [AutoRig Pro](https://blendermarket.com/products/auto-rig-pro) for less headache when rigging models but it offers different versions like "Full 10 seats" or "Full 20 seats" and I wonder what those "seats" are. Can someone explain please? And which version should I get for rigging... Idk a few separate pokemon models or something.

Answer (score 2):

Seats refers to the number of users who can use the product with the license you buy:

> A **per-seat license** (or "named user license") is a software license model based on the number of individual users who have access to a digital service or product. For example, 50-user per-seat license would mean that up to 50 individual named users can access the program.

(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per-seat_license))